# How to use wxWidgets with SFML?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, sfml

I am making a series of applications on physics simulations and until now I've done some of them using purely the handy SFML library. Now I want to add some GUI elements to them. I am just a little bit familiar with wxWidgets framework and wxFrames but have no idea how wxDc works, which seems to be at the core of SFML-wxWidgets integration. I will list my queries one by one.

1. My shot at the old tutorial provided by [SFML dev webpage](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/graphics-wxwidgets.php): The final code, after correcting for the trivial errors looks like this:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <wx/wx.h>

class wxSFMLCanvas : public wxControl, public sf::RenderWindow
{
public:
    wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow* Parent = NULL, wxWindowID Id = -1, const wxPoint& Position = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& Size = wxDefaultSize, long Style = 0);
    virtual ~wxSFMLCanvas();

private:
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
    virtual void OnUpdate();
    void OnIdle(wxIdleEvent&);
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&);
    void OnEraseBackground(wxEraseEvent&);
    void OnSize(wxSizeEvent&);
};

void wxSFMLCanvas::OnUpdate()
{
}

void wxSFMLCanvas::OnIdle(wxIdleEvent&)
{
    // Send a paint message when the control is idle, to ensure maximum framerate
    Refresh();
}

void wxSFMLCanvas::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
{
    // Prepare the control to be repainted
    wxPaintDC Dc(this);
    // Let the derived class do its specific stuff
    OnUpdate();
    // Display on screen
    display();
}

void wxSFMLCanvas::OnEraseBackground(wxEraseEvent&)
{
}

void wxSFMLCanvas::OnSize(wxSizeEvent&)
{
}

wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow* Parent, wxWindowID Id, const wxPoint& Position, const wxSize& Size, long Style) :
    wxControl(Parent, Id, Position, Size, Style) {
    sf::RenderWindow::create(GetHandle());
}

wxSFMLCanvas::~wxSFMLCanvas()
{
}

class MyCanvas : public wxSFMLCanvas
{
    sf::CircleShape circ;
public:
    MyCanvas(wxWindow* Parent, wxWindowID Id, wxPoint& Position, wxSize& Size, long Style = 0) : wxSFMLCanvas(Parent, Id, Position, Size, Style) {
        // specify circle
        circ.setRadius(50.0f);
        circ.setOrigin(50.0f,50.0f);
        circ.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        circ.setPosition(100.0f, 100.0f);
    }
private:
    virtual void OnUpdate() {
        // Clear the view
        clear(sf::Color(0, 128, 128));

        // Display the circle in the view
        draw(circ);
    }
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "SFML wxWidgets", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 600)) {
        wxPoint tmp1 = wxPoint(50, 50);
        wxSize tmp2 = wxSize(700, 500);
        new MyCanvas(this, wxID_ANY, tmp1, tmp2);
    }
};

class MyApplication : public wxApp
{
private:

    virtual bool OnInit()
    {
        // Create the main window
        MyFrame* MainFrame = new MyFrame;
        MainFrame->Show();

        return true;
    }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApplication);
```

This throws a bunch of unresolved externals:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct wxEventTable const * __cdecl wxSFMLCanvas::GetEventTable(void)const " (?GetEventTable@wxSFMLCanvas@@MEBAPEBUwxEventTable@@XZ) test1   C:\Users\rajat\source\repos\test1\test1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class wxEventHashTable & __cdecl wxSFMLCanvas::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (?GetEventHashTable@wxSFMLCanvas@@MEBAAEAVwxEventHashTable@@XZ)    test1   C:\Users\rajat\source\repos\test1\test1.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)    test1   C:\Users\rajat\source\repos\test1\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) 1
```

Furthermore, I don't quite understand how in this example wxWidgets is supposed to draw the contents of a `sf::RenderWindow`. It will be very helpful if someone can rectify this barebone code so that it works. And also hopefully explain how it works.

2. Is there an alternative to wxWidgets that would work with SFML, or has a handy tool for fast and simple graphical library? The only requirement is that I should be able to compile it on MSVS for x64 framework and statically link to my application. I considered Qt, but I can't get it to either compile on my own, or even if I do, it's only the 32-bit shared library configuration.
3. How is the code supposed to work? The `sf::RenderWindow` is created using `sf::RenderWindow::create(GetHandle())`. Is it supposed to draw everything on its own? Or do I have to copy the bitmap of the SFML window and draw on the `wxControl` by myself? It will be really helpful if someone could shed some light on how it's supposed to work.

Comment: ***Is there an alternative to wxWidgets that would work with SFML*** Qt should work very well for this.

Comment: One other comment about this. Remember that binaries for c++ libraries are usually only compatible with msvc or mingw you usually can't use mingw c++ binaries for msvc  or vise-versa. Make sure you have the correct binaries for whatever compiler you are using. Also Visual Studio versions 2015 to 2019 are compatible with each other but not compatible with any other version of msvc.

Comment: @drescherjm I updated the question with the errors. I could use Qt if I could compile it for x64 architecture in static linking mode, but I simply can't. I compiled both SFML and wxWidgets on MSVS on x64 static linking config, and I am using the corresponding preprocessor directives for static linking. They individually work fine.

Comment: I use 64bit Qt for 13 years now at work  but never as a static library. Instead I generate a NSIS  installer which has all the required dlls which also includes the ability to install the msvc redistributable as well.

Comment: Maybe this is realted to your problem: [https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=40656](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=40656)

Comment: @drescherjm I have DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()  macro in the `wxSFMLCanvas` class declaration. As for an Qt installer, that's exactly why I'm still not using it, these are meant to be a few kilobytes of portable simulation applications, doesn't really make sense to have a whole installer for them.

Comment: I can see the point of that. My installers are 20 to 40MB in size..

Comment: @drescherjm I could create some global variables, update them using wxWidgets GUI controls, create an SFML window in a different thread, and use the variables as parameters in the simulations. But I don't want to unleash the problems with threads and global variables if I can help it.

Comment: Guys, Qt license prevents you frm lnking statically unless you pay. 2OP: How do you compile that code? What options do you use? I presume you build wxWidgets - how? What configurations?

Comment: @Igor I built it using the given solution for MSVC by wxWidgets, in all of the x64/x86 and debug/release modes. When I compile my application, I do it in the x64, debug mode and add the include directories and set the library path to `C:\Program Files\wxWidgets\lib\vc_x64_lib;`, but give no specific .lib files in the linker->input->additional dependencies.

Comment: @RajatMondal, please open the `minimal` sample solution inside MSVC and look at its properties. Then do the same thing in your project. Then it should compile cleanly. Make sure in the sample you select an appropriate target to look at -= i.e. static vs dynamic.

Comment: @How do I find the static properties of the `minimal` solution? I can only switch release/debug modes and architecture inside the property manager. Edit: I can see them in the property manager pane on the right side, but the wx_setup property sheet or the other sheets don't have anything extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to using `DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE` but not using any `wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE/wxEND_EVENT_TABLE`, i.e. you never define your event table nor connect any event handlers.

I don't know anything about SFML, so I can't really help you with the rest, but apparently drawing is supposed to be done from your `wxEVT_PAINT` handler -- once you connect it -- by just calling `sf::RenderWindow::Display()`.

Comment: Again, sorry, I don't know anything about SFML, but to me it seems like `Display()` should work. Does it work for you in SFML-only example, without using wx?

Comment: I got it to work. I was just confused by so many classes and unused member functions, so I started deleting everything that wasn't needed and everything finally came together. I posted a barebone code that displays a circle. And my second assumption was right.. SFML can display everything on its own, I don't have to draw on `wxControl` by myself. But thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got them to work together. Here's a minimal code that shows a circle on a button click:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <wx/wx.h>

class wxSFMLCanvas : public wxControl, public sf::RenderWindow
{
public:
    wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow* Parent = NULL, wxWindowID Id = -1, const wxPoint& Position = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& Size = wxDefaultSize, long Style = 0);
    virtual ~wxSFMLCanvas();
};

wxSFMLCanvas::wxSFMLCanvas(wxWindow* Parent, wxWindowID Id, const wxPoint& Position, const wxSize& Size, long Style) :
    wxControl(Parent, Id, Position, Size, Style) {
    sf::RenderWindow::create(GetHandle());
}

wxSFMLCanvas::~wxSFMLCanvas() {
}

class cMain : public wxFrame
{
    wxButton* m_btn1 = nullptr;
    wxSFMLCanvas* mycanv = nullptr;
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
public:
    cMain();
    void onBtnClicked(wxCommandEvent &evt);
};


wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(cMain,wxFrame)
    EVT_BUTTON(10001, onBtnClicked)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()


cMain::cMain() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Window", wxPoint(30, 30), wxSize(800, 600)) {
    mycanv = new wxSFMLCanvas(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(700, 500));
    m_btn1 = new wxButton(this, 10001, "button1", wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(100, 50));
}

void cMain::onBtnClicked(wxCommandEvent& evt) {
    sf::CircleShape circ(50.0f);
    circ.setOrigin(50.0f, 50.0f);
    circ.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    circ.setPosition(350, 250);
    mycanv->draw(circ);
    mycanv->display();
}

class myApp : public wxApp
{
    cMain* m_Frame1 = nullptr;
public:
    myApp();
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(myApp);

myApp::myApp() {

}

bool myApp::OnInit() {
    // Create the main window
    m_Frame1 = new cMain;
    m_Frame1->Show();
    return true;
}
```

The executable of this code(everything statically linked) are ~10MB(debug mode) ~4MB(release mode). I'm leaving this code here in case anyone else finds this useful.